# EER Diagram, am I doing this right?

Tags: database, foreign-keys, relationship, database-schema, eer-model

For every table I'm adding a row id_company (relationship) to the companies table, because each company will have its own records. Am I doing it right?

[image]

Comment: Could you explain what your database is about?

Comment: It's a database for an ERP. But it's incomplete yet.